# yarn workspace package always installs in root

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I am using `lerna` with `yarn workspaces`.

I have 3 sub-repos in my monorepo. I add `husky` in `sub-repo-1`'s package.json and then run `yarn`.

It appears that `husky` ends up being installed in the root's node_modules instead of `sub-repo-1`'s node_modules, which seems to me a bug, because as far as I understand, if package is not used more than 1 sub-repo, then it should be in its own sub-repo's node_modules.

Any idea ?